# Clean build cache and No debuggable processes

Tags: android

strong text
I'm  currently taking android studio for beginners and I'm having trouble running an app on my phone, in the logcat it states "no debuggable processes" in red and when I run the app it stated
"Task execution finished 'cleanBuildCache'", 
The name of the app is "Courtcounter" but it now it states "court counter clean Build Cache" right before I press the run button.
I unchecked the enable intant run box in the build, execution, deployment part of the preference but it did not work. I'm using android studio 3.1.3. I also tried clean project and rebuild project. Any suggestions? Please be as basic as possible when explaining because I'm new to Android Studio and I still don't understand some of the terminologies. 
Here are the screen shots;

[first screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DwEyC.png)

[cleanbuilcache screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xLgwY.png)

Comment: please share the screenshot of error

Comment: How do I do screen shot on stack overflow?

Comment: click on edit then click on 6 icon of body from left then upload your screen shot image.

Comment: is the app running on your phone at all? because no debuggable processes simply saying app is not running on your phone! you can switch to run instead of logcat to see if the run is showing the processes.

Comment: It's not running at all unfortunately, I pressed run instead of the logcat and this was what was displayed:7:46:48 AM:7:46:48 AM: Executing task 'cleanBuildCache'...

Executing tasks: [cleanBuildCache]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
:app:cleanBuildCache

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1s
1 actionable task: 1 executed
7:46:50 AM: Task execution finished 'cleanBuildCache'.

Answer (score 2):

**Android Studio version <= 3.0**

Try enabling ADB integration.

`Tools` -> `Android` -> and check `Enable ADB Integration`

**Android Studio version > 3.0**

Preferences -> Build, Execution & Deployment -> Debugger

Then toggle the box `Use libusb backend`

Hope it helps :)

Comment: I tried it but it didn't work, I'm not even getting a "select deployment" box to select my phone. Also, how do put my screenshot on stack over flow?